# Получить файл из OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

Как вместо кода xml передать полученный файл из OpenFileDialog в XDocument.Parse?

```
var d = new OpenFileDialog()
{
Filter = "XML files (*.xml)|*.xml"
};
if (d.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
}

XDocument xd = XDocument.Parse(@"<data><name>Денис</name><pass>123</pass> <age>30</age></data>");
```

Вот так выдает ошибку (Недопустимые данные на корневом уровне)

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Parse(d.FileName);
```

Может еще Load какой-то сделать нужно предварительно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```
XDocument doc;
var d = new OpenFileDialog()
{
    Filter = "XML files (*.xml)|*.xml"
};
if (d.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    doc = XDocument.Load(d.FileName);
}
```

Comment: а дальше `XDocument xd = XDocument.Parse(????)` как записать?

Comment: @Андрей А зачем? `Parse` нужен для преобразования строки в `XDocument`. А `Load` с файлом сам справляется, если конечно в файле валидный XML.

Comment: О. Заработало. Спасибо.