# WinForms c# . Проложить путь к файлу

Tags: c#, winforms

Как добавить в своей программе на c# WinForms searcher , при нажатии которого будет выскакивать проводник и нужно будет выбрать файл , после чего содержание этого файла должно быть прочитано?

Comment: Используйте [`FileDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Андрей Можете это записать в виде ответа и с примером кода . P.S. Я уже читал эту статью , не совсем понял , из-за этого решил задать вопрос на stack'e.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простое решение, добавьте проверки на успех после диалога, и на существование файла

```csarp
        private string OpenDialog()
        {
            var opd = new OpenFileDialog();
            opd.Filter = "*.txt | *.txt";
            opd.ShowDialog();
            return opd.FileName;
        }

        private void ReadFile()
        {
            // здесь выполняем проверки
            var data = File.ReadAllText(OpenDialog());
        }
```

Comment: А если открыть диалог, не выбрать файл и закрыть его? :) Лучше строку `opd.ShowDialog();` заменить на: `if(opd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)`. И в `ReadFile()`, соответственно, немного подправить.

Comment: верно , я написал об этом , "добавить проверки"

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю вам поможет [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498503/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B8%D0%B7-openfiledialog) или [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136383/reading-a-text-file-using-openfiledialog-in-windows-forms).

В целом, есть хороший [ресурс](https://professorweb.ru), там много ответов на подобные вопросы.